C++ and Node.js Binding Issue
I am working on a C++ application that integrates with Node.js using the N-API (via napi) / node_api.h, where I expose C++ classes and methods to JavaScript. Specifically, I have a TEAM class with a vector of CTF_player objects, and I want to fetch a player's name using the GetPlayerName method.
Here’s what’s happening:
The first call to GetPlayerName works fine and returns the expected result.
However, when I try to call the same method again, nothing happens after that point, and no errors are thrown.
I suspect there may be an issue with memory management or accessing the vector of CTF_player objects (members[index]).
class CTF_player
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int score;

public:
    // Constructor
    CTF_player(const std::string &playerName, int playerScore)
        : name(playerName), score(playerScore) {}

    // Getter for name
    std::string getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }

    // Getter for score
    int getScore() const
    {
        return score;
    }

    // Setter for name
    void setName(const std::string &newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    // Setter for score
    void setScore(int newScore)
    {
        score = newScore;
    }
};

class TEAM
{
public:
    std::vector<CTF_player> members;

    std::string GetPlayerName(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= members.size())
        {
            return ""; // Handle out-of-bounds case
        }
        return members[index].getName();
    }

    void addMember(const CTF_player &player)
    {
        members.push_back(player);
    }
};

napi_value GetPlayerName(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info)
{
    // Arguments parsing
    size_t argc = 2;
    napi_value args[2];
    napi_status status = napi_get_cb_info(env, info, &argc, args, nullptr, nullptr);

    TEAM *team;
    napi_get_value_external(env , args[0] , (void**)&team); 
    int index;
    status = napi_get_value_int32(env, args[1], &index);

    std::string name = team->GetPlayerName(index);
    napi_value js_name;
    napi_create_string_utf8(env, name.c_str(), name.size(), &js_name);
    return js_name;
}

let team1 = CreateCTF_TEAM("Team A", 1);
console.log("Team created:", GetTeamName(team1));
CreateCTFPlayer("bilal" , 1 , team1);
console.log("p1" , GetPlayerName(team1 , 0));

//after this the rest of the code is skipped
console.log("p1" , GetPlayerName(team1 , 0));

let team2 = CreateCTF_TEAM("Team B", 1);
console.log("Team created:", GetTeamName(team2));

After the first call to GetPlayerName, the subsequent calls do not return the expected result, and it seems that nothing happens after the second call.
I suspect that the problem might be related to the std::string handling or how the C++ object is being managed in memory between JavaScript calls.
Could the memory management (via napi_create_external) or vector indexing be causing issues?
How can I ensure that the objects remain valid and accessible between calls in Node.js?
I would appreciate any advice on how to solve this issue or where to look further.

Ensure that the TEAM object passed as an external reference is correctly allocated and remains valid. Use napi_create_external to pass the pointer and associate a finalizer to prevent accidental deallocation:
napi_value CreateTeam(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info) {
    TEAM* team = new TEAM(); // Allocate dynamically to ensure persistence
    napi_value external;
    napi_status status = napi_create_external(env, team, [](napi_env env, void* finalize_data, void* hint) {
        TEAM* team = static_cast<TEAM*>(finalize_data);
        delete team; // Clean up memory when the object is garbage collected
    }, nullptr, &external);

    if (status != napi_ok) {
        napi_throw_error(env, nullptr, "Failed to create external TEAM object");
    }

    return external;
}

